# dplyr - sum of multiple columns using regular expressions

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, tidyverse

For the dataset mtcars2

```
mtcars2 = mtcars
mtcars2 = mtcars2 %>% mutate(cyl9=cyl, disp9=disp, gear2=gear)
```

I want to get a new column which is the sum of multiple columns, by using regular expressions to capture the pattern.

This is a solution, however this is done by hard-coding

```
select(mtcars2, cyl9) + select(mtcars2, disp9) + select(mtcars2, gear2)
```

I tried something like this but it gives me a number instead of a vector

```
mtcars2 %>% select(matches("[0-9]")) %>% sum
```

Please dplyr solutions only, since i need to apply these functions to a sql table later on.

Thanks!

Update..
I need the solution to work on sql tables, data setup as follow..

```
mydb <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "")
dbWriteTable(mydb, "mt", mtcars)
mt.sql=tbl(mydb, "mt")
mt.sql = mt.sql %>% mutate(cyl9=cyl, disp9=disp, gear2=gear)
```

reduce(), rowSums(), rowwise() does not work on sql tables, ive tried those and they give me errors.

I've tried,

```
mt.sql %>% rowwise()
```

Error: is.data.frame(data) is not TRUE

```
mt.sql %>% select(matches("[0-9]")) %>% mutate(sum=rowSums(.))
```

Error in UseMethod("escape") : 
  no applicable method for 'escape' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_dbi', 'tbl_sql', 'tbl_lazy', 'tbl')"

```
mt.sql %>% select(matches("[0-9]")) %>% reduce(`+`)
```

Error in .x + .y : non-numeric argument to binary operator

If i switch mt.sql to mtcars2, they all work, so i guess this is a sql table issue.

Comment: You need `rowSums` instead of `sum`: `mtcars2 %>% select(matches("[0-9]")) %>% rowSums()`

Comment: @mt1022 Add as an answer?

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but rowSums dont work on sql tables.

Comment: Updated.. thanks guys..

Comment: @RonakShah Those solution only works on dfs.. ive updated my post.. thanks

Comment: Can you edit to show the errors generated when using `tbl`.

Comment: @neilfws errors added.. thanks,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that the SQL constraint prevents use of more simple and elegant solutions such as `rowSums` and `reduce`, I offer a more hack-y answer that brings us back to the more basic `new_col = a + b + c + ... + n`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

# get the variable names and form a text equation
col_eqn <- paste0(str_subset(colnames(mtcars), "[a-z]", collapse = " + ")

# run a normal  mutate function parsing and evaluating the equation
mtcars %>% mutate(new_col = eval(parse(text = col_eqn)))

# mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb new_col
# 1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 328.980
# 2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 329.795
# 3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 259.580
# 4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 426.135
# 5  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 590.310
# 6  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 385.540
# 7  14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4 656.920
# 8  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2 270.980
# 9  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2 299.570
# 10 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4 350.460
```

Comment: `mt.sql %>% select(matches("[0-9]")) %>% names()` does not seem to give the names.. it came up as "src" "ops" instead of the names. But `mt.sql %>% select(matches("[0-9]"))` do give the names..

Comment: Would it not be easier at this point to construct an SQL string and execute that in the old fashioned way?

Comment: Try `colnames` to get the column names - unlike `names`, it works with tibbles (plain and sql-flavour), data frames, data tables...

Comment: `colnames` saves you having to do the whole head/collect stuff. Use `stringr` package and it becomes: `col_eqn = paste0(str_subset(colnames(mt.sql),"[0-9]"),collapse=" + ")`

Answer (score 2):

We could use the `tidyverse` options

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars2 %>%
      select(matches("[0-9]")) %>%
      reduce(`+`) #%>%
      #if needed to create a new column   
      #mutate(mtcars2, newcol = .)

#[1] 170.0 170.0 116.0 267.0 371.0 234.0 371.0 154.7 148.8 177.6 177.6 286.8
#[13] 286.8 286.8 483.0 471.0 451.0  86.7  83.7  79.1 127.1 329.0 315.0 361.0
#[25] 411.0  87.0 129.3 104.1 364.0 156.0 314.0 129.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but reduce() do not work on sql tables..
Please check the update.. Thanks!